# Find and delete HTML5 data-* attributes with bs4

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

HTML5 files may contain [custom data-* attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

I want to find and delete all of these **data-*** attributes with **bs4**.

According to the the **bs4** documentation, it's possible to search for these attributes using the **attrs** property.

For example:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data_soup = BeautifulSoup('<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>')
data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-foo": "value"})
```

However, the following line does not work:

```
data_soup.find_all(attrs={re.compile('data.*') : True})
```

1. What regular expression do I need to use find all **data-*** attributes (regardless of their values)?
2. Once found, how do I delete them using **del**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, to delete attribute you simply use `del` on `tag.attrs`:

```
data = '''
<ul>
  <li data-animal-type="bird" data-other="this is other data">Owl</li>
  <li data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li>
  <li data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>
</ul>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print('Original soup:')
print(soup)
print('-' * 80)

for tag in soup.find_all(lambda t: any(i.startswith('data-') for i in t.attrs)):
    for attr in list(tag.attrs):
        if attr.startswith('data-'):
            del tag.attrs[attr]

print()
print('Soup without data-* tags:')
print(soup)
print('-' * 80)
```

This prints:

```
Original soup:
<html><body><ul>
<li data-animal-type="bird" data-other="this is other data">Owl</li>
<li data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li>
<li data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>
</ul></body></html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Soup without data-* tags:
<html><body><ul>
<li>Owl</li>
<li>Salmon</li>
<li>Tarantula</li>
</ul></body></html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```